# Simple bash script to split csv file by week number

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to separate a large pipe-delimited file based on a week number field.  The file contains data for a full year thus having 53 weeks.  I am hoping to create a loop that does the following:

```
1) check if week number is less than 10 - if it is paste a '0' in front
2) use grep to send the rows to a file (ie `grep '|01|' bigFile.txt > smallFile.txt` )
3) gzip the smaller file (ie `gzip smallFile.txt`)
4) repeat
```

Is there a resource that would show how to do this?

EDIT :

Data looks like this:

```
1|@gmail|1|0|0|0|1|01|com
1|@yahoo|0|1|0|0|0|27|com
```

The column I care about is the 2nd from the right.

EDIT 2:

Here's the script I'm using but it's not functioning:

```
for (( i = 1; i <= 12; i++ )); do
    #statements
    echo 'i :'$i

    q=$i
    # echo $q
    # $q==10

    if [[ q -lt 10 ]]; then
        #statements
        k='0'$q
        echo $k
        grep '|$k|' 20150226_train.txt > 'weeks_files/week'$k
        gzip weeks_files/week $k

    fi
    if [[ q -gt 9 ]]; then
        #statements
        echo $q
        grep \'|$q|\' 20150226_train.txt > 'weeks_files/week'$q
        gzip 'weeks_files/week'$q
    fi


done
```

Comment: What does the file look like?

Comment: Please provide data sample.

Comment: Just bash is probably the wrong tool to use. Awk or Perl are likely to work much more nicely.

Comment: Note that you're talking about _53_ weeks, but your main loop only loops from _1 to 12_.

Comment: @mklement0: you are correct - that's just for debugging to get a mix of single and double digit #'s.

Comment: @screechOwl: Did none of the answers work for you?

Comment: I ended up trying shelter's answer and while it ran, the files didn't separate properly.  Next I tried 'csvfix', which seemed to work then it crashed.  Next I tried writing it in python until I hit a NULL byte exception which I'm currently working on now.

Answer (score 3):

Very simple in awk ...

```
awk -F'|' '{ print > ("smallfile-" $(NF-1) ".txt";) }' bigfile.txt
```

<sup>Edit: brackets added for "original-awk".</sup>

Comment: That's indeed by far the simplest - and also most efficient - solution; note that at least with BSD awk you need to use `("smallfile-" $(NF-1) ".txt")` (enclosing in parentheses) for this to work (GNU awk and mawk are fine without the parentheses). If you throw in `gzip smallfile-*`, you have a complete solution.

Comment: (Addendum, after the OP added code for generating output files implying a naming scheme: what this solution doesn't do - general name and location details aside - is to 0-pad the indices that become part of the filenames.)

Comment: @mklement0 except, the example original file and the file that the grep commands require already has the zeros so editing the value is not needed because it's treated as a string. But if the input does have a mixture awk has a sprintf function you can use.

Comment: You're absolutely right: the OP's sample input data and code suggest that the input week numbers are indeed already zero-padded (as I myself have noted elsewhere - off to take my memory pills).

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there.

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( i = 1; i <= 12; i++ )); do
    #statements
    echo 'i :'$i

    q=$i
    # echo $q
    # $q==10

    #OLD if [[ q -lt 10 ]]; then
    if [[ $q -lt 10 ]]; then
        #statements
        k='0'$q
        echo $k
#OLD        grep '|$k|' 20150226_train.txt > 'weeks_files/week'$k
        grep "|$k|" 20150226_train.txt > 'weeks_files/week'$k
#OLD    gzip weeks_files/week $k
        gzip weeks_files/week$k

    #OLD fi
    #OLD if [[ q -gt 9 ]]; then
    elif [[ $q -gt 9 ]] ; then
        #statements
        echo $q
        #OLD grep \'|$q|\' 20150226_train.txt > 'weeks_files/week'$q
        grep "|$q|" 20150226_train.txt > 'weeks_files/week'$q
       gzip 'weeks_files/week'$q
    fi
done
```

You didn't alway use `$` in front of your variable values. You can only get away with using k or q without a $ inside the shell arthimetic substitution feature, ie `z=$(( x+k))` or just to operate on a variable like `(( k++ ))`. There are others.

You need to learn the difference between single quoting and dbl-quoting. You need to use dbl-quoting when you want a value substituted for a variable, as in your lines

```
    grep "|$q|" 20150226_train.txt > 'weeks_files/week'$q
```

and others.

I'm guessing that your use of `grep \'|$q|\' 20150226_train.txt` was an attempt to get the value of `$q`.

The way to get comfortable with debugging this sort of situation is to set the shell debugging option with `set -x` (turn it off with `set +x`). You'll see each line that is executed with the values substituted for the variables. Advanced debugging requires `echo "varof Interset now = $var"` (print statements). Also, you can use `set -vx` (and `set +vx`) to see each line or **block** of code before it is executed, and then the `-x` output will show which lines where acctually executed. For your script, you'd see the whole `if ... elfi ...fi` block printed, and then just the lines of `-x` output with values for variables. It can be confusing, even after years of looking at it. ;-)

So you can go thru and remove all lines with the prefix #OLD, and I'm hoping your code will work for you.

IHTH

Comment: Kudos for the sound _bash_ advice, but it's really worth pointing out that solving this problem in pure bash is the wrong approach, as evidenced by the simplicity of [user3710044's awk-based answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28907301/45375).

Comment: @mklement0, yes I agree that user3710044 is better solution. Had to run out and couldn't finish up. I think the code size speaks for itself. If the O.P. is just learning how `bash` works, this wasn't a bad non-beginner project. And I like Dale_Reagen's test-bed approach (for which I hvae been chastised for in the past! ;-) ) ! Good luck to all!

Comment: @shellter:I was able to run this but the files did not separate properly.  I ended up using a utility called 'csvfix' instead.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
mkdir -p weeks_files &&
awk -F'|' '
    { file=sprintf("weeks_files/week%2d",$(NF-1)); print > file }
    !seen[file]++ { print file }
' 20150226_train.txt |
xargs gzip
```

If your data is ordered so that all of the rows for a given week number are contiguous you can make it simpler and more efficient:

```
mkdir -p weeks_files &&
awk -F'|' '
    $(NF-1) != prev { file=sprintf("weeks_files/week%2d",$(NF-1)); print file }
    { print > file; prev=$(NF-1) }
' 20150226_train.txt |
xargs gzip
```

Comment: Nice first solution, but wouldn't the second one send _all_ lines to the _same_ output file, given that there's only 1 input file?

Answer (score 1):

There are certainly a number of approaches - the 'awk' line below will reformat your data. If you take a sequential approach, then:

1) awk to reformat

```
awk -F '|' '{printf "%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%02d|%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9}' SOURCE_FILE > bigFile.txt
```

2) loop through the weeks, create small file an zip it

```
for N in {01..53} 
do 
    grep "|${N}|" bigFile.txt > smallFile.${N}.txt
    gzip smallFile.${N}.txt
done
```

3) test script showing reformat step

```
#!/bin/bash
function show_data {
# Data set w/9 'fields'
# 1| 2  |3|4|5|6|7| 8|9
cat << EOM
1|@gmail|1|0|0|0|1|01|com
1|@gmail|1|0|0|0|1|2|com
1|@gmail|1|0|0|0|1|5|com
1|@yahoo|0|1|0|0|0|27|com
EOM
}
###
function stars {
echo "## $@ ##"
}
###
stars "Raw data"
show_data
stars "Modified data"
#                                 1| 2| 3| 4| 5| 6| 7|   8|9 ##
show_data | awk -F '|' '{printf "%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%02d|%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9}'
```

Sample run:

```
$ bash test.sh
## Raw data ##
1|@gmail|1|0|0|0|1|01|com
1|@gmail|1|0|0|0|1|2|com
1|@gmail|1|0|0|0|1|5|com
1|@yahoo|0|1|0|0|0|27|com
## Modified data ##
1|@gmail|1|0|0|0|1|01|com
1|@gmail|1|0|0|0|1|02|com
1|@gmail|1|0|0|0|1|05|com
1|@yahoo|0|1|0|0|0|27|com
```

Comment: There's probably no need to reformat the _input_ file - note how the OP only struggles to create the 0-padded indices for _grepping_. A caveat for bash _3.x_ users: `{01..53}` doesn't create `01`, `02`, ..., but `1`, `2`, ... - for the zero-padding to work, you need bash _4+_.

Comment: Whether needed OR NOT, it was part of the '?';  I certainly like the awk solution, however it does not literally complete the request and it is not explained (yes, perhaps it's obvious if you are already somewhat familiar with awk/bash scripting, but not for a noob.)

Comment: Yes, it is unfortunate that the one-line awk solution lacks an explanation and is incomplete (I've added the missing `gzip` command in a comment, but a complete, fully explained answer is certainly preferable).

Comment: IMHO if you explain your answer the OP skims the explanation, says "thanks" and walks away without really learning very much whereas if they investigate it themselves to try to understand it and then ask questions then they learn a lot more, not least of which is where to find the documentation on the tool(s) so they can learn about more than this one answer. You also waste a fair bit of your time explaining thing that might be glaringly obvious to the OP. I do understand not everyone shares that opinion :-)

Comment: @EdMorton: I hear you, but at the extreme end of that spectrum lie unexplained answers full of arcana that make the less experienced just give up trying to understand them. Also, if a reader is not _willing_ to learn, a (partially) unexplained answer won't magically make them perform their own investigation. Re "You also waste a fair bit of your time explaining things that might be glaringly obvious to the OP": That's a definite possibility, but remember that answers are never _just_ for the OP, and other (later) readers may have very different skill levels.